# Issue to place an image at the bottom and outside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I'd like to place an image (this will be a triangle down) to the **bottom** of the white background but **outside of it** (the top of my image should touch the bottom of the DIV). How could I achieve this? I have tried the following but that doesn't work - the image remains within the DIV despite the adjusted margins.

https://jsfiddle.net/63s86hf9/8/

```
  </div><img src="http://placehold.it/92x45" class="triangle-outside" alt="" width="92" height="45">
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.triangle-outside {
  display: block;
  margin: 45px auto 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this could be considered as a different question. First question was to place the image at the top and within the DIV. This one is about placing the DIV at the bottom and outside the DIV.

Comment: just let me know, outside of `section` or `container` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do it with many method but one of these is using `position: absolute`:

```
.triangle-outside {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -45px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63s86hf9/9/)**

but you need set `position: relative` for parent `(section)` and add `margin-bottom` to it. and note that do not use same `id` for both `section`, `ID` must be `unique`. this method is cross browser but also you can use `after` or `before`.

```
#services2::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -45px;
    margin: auto;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/92x45') no-repeat;
    width: 92px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63s86hf9/10/)**

and then remove `.triangle-outside`. but if you want to use `href` on it so you must use prev method.

*I set a background color for body to testing, just remove it later.*

Answer (score 1):

Your image has a negative margin of -80px, and your section a padding of 75px.
So you have a 5px differences making it look like it was inside the div.

You can :

- Replace `80px` by `75px`
- Change this ugly negative margin to a method using absolute/relative positions
- `:before/:after` pseudo elements could also do the thing if this is the same image everytime.

You don't have problem with the white div. It's just that body background is white too soo you think it's inside but it's in fact outside.
https://jsfiddle.net/oL40awap/1/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think your answer relates to the image at the top of the DIV, I have no concern with that one. The issue is with the one at the bottom of the DIV. I have created a new fiddle to avoid confusion.

Comment: See my last line. My browser is chrome, everything is fine. See this fork : https://jsfiddle.net/oL40awap/1/ I added a red background for you to see. Your image at bottom is outside the white div, inside the red section, and has a top-margin of 45px.